# Transactions at the MySQL console

Tags: mysql

MySQL comes with a nice SQL prompt.

One of it's commands is `source` which reads in commands from a text file and executes them as if they were typed at the prompt.

Imagine such a text file with the following lines:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
UPDATE ....;
UPDATE ....;
DELETE FROM ...;
COMMIT;
```

If there is a syntax or other error on any of those SQL statements in the middle, they still continue to execute the rest, including the `COMMIT`!  Ouch!

How can you make it so that if any of the commands fail, the transaction and the script are aborted?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to [declare an exception handler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html):

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER
    FOR SQLEXCEPTION, SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND
        ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Aha very promising.  Sadly it just tells me there's an error in the syntax; it doesn't say what exactly.  I imagine that this can only be declared in a procedure or something, and that furthermore if I put my code in a procedure its not session-local and it can't use session @variables?

Comment: That would indeed be correct. An alternative solution could be to do a `SHOW WARNINGS` // `SHOW ERRORS` (or COUNT them) and at the end COMMIT/ROLLBACK based on the (COUNT) of those.